# Autoscrolling content to bottom works in Chrome, but not in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, autoscroll

I'm making a chat interface, so as people chat and the page gets filled, it needs to automatically scroll down to show the newest messages without the user having to manually scroll down. It works in Chrome, but not in Safari. Here is the particular line that is not working

```
    document.getElementById('chatbox').scrollTop = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
```

If the div ID is "chatbox", what do I need to put in the place of this line for it to work in Safari? Also, to clarify, despite it called "scrolltop" it scrolls to the bottom (which is what I want), but only in chrome.

Comment: why not use `scroll-y` or `overflow-y` to `auto` ?

Comment: I am new to coding, and that was the line I had found to be working. I will look into your suggestions, and report back. Thanks

Comment: I set the style for the chatbox with "overflow-y: auto", and it doesnt work. It creates a scroll bar after the view gets full of messages, but it doesnt scroll down automatically as new messages occur. Also, this method doesnt work in chrome either.

Comment: Can you send a the code via jsfiddle or pastebin?

Comment: It is working now. It turned out to be an issue with "Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;" which Safari didnt like. Changed it to a number like "100000000" and it works now.

Comment: Okay great! finally got you working

Answer (score 1):

Safari didnt like "Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;". Replaced with an actual integer (ie 1000000) and it autoscrolled.